# Can't print specific indexes from a list along side strings

Tags: python, list

This is the error I'm getting and I roughly understanding what its saying but I always thought you could print specific list indexes without changing its type:
[image: Error Message]

The code I'm using is:

```
Board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def CreateBoard(Board):
  print("   |   |")
  print(" " + Board[7] + " | " + Board[8] + " | " + Board[9])
  print("   |   |")
  print('-----------')
  print("   |   |")
  print(" " + Board[4] + " | " + Board[5] + " | " + Board[6])
  print("   |   |")
  print("-----------")
  print("   |   |")
  print("  " + Board[1] + " | " + Board[2] + " | " + Board[3])
  print("   |   |")

CreateBoard(Board)
```

I want to keep it as a list value when I print it because I need to print specific values in specific places and this is the only method I'm most familiar with!
I've realised the issue seems to be its trying to add the values up like an equation so now I need to find out how to prevent it from adding them and just printing it alongside the string.

Comment: Do you do any math with the elements in `Board`?  You could just store them as strings.

Comment: You can print indices without changing the type. The issue isn't created when you print, but when you try to add a string to the index (you can't add a string to an integer)

Comment: I modify some of the values in the list at different points in the code by using equations like 'Board[Move - 1] = Letter' not sure if that would count as maths though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the error it's giving you.

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
or,
TypeError: You can only concatenate string, (not "int") to String
```

Therefore, you can convert type (to string):

```
print(" " + str(Board[6]) + " | " + str(Board[7]) + " | " + str(Board[8]))
```

Will print the following:

```
7 | 8 | 9
```

However, a better way to do this is by using String formatting:

```
print("| {} | {} | {}".format(Board[1], Board[5], Board[7]))
```

This will print the following:

```
| 2 | 6 | 8
```

Comment: You are welcome. Also wanted to point out you have "Board[9]" at one place, It will give you an error saying out of index because your indices run from 0 to 8.